# apply function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, apply, spidermonkey

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm currently trying to figure out why (in [Spidermonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey))

```
[].concat.apply([1], [[2]])
```

returns the expected `[1, 2]`, but

```
Array.concat.apply([1], [[2]])
```

returns `[2]` instead of `[1, 2]`.

Could someone provide a good explanation?

Comment: What does `Array.prototype.concat.apply([1], [[2]])` return?

Comment: Which browser are you using? `Array.concat` does not exist in Chrome.

Comment: Firefox has a "concat()" on the Array prototype (but not on the Array constructor object).

Comment: strange it allows you to run the second statement, it should be `(new Array).concat.apply([1], [[2]])` witch should return the expected result

Comment: `Array.concat` ==> `function concat() {[native code]}`

Comment: Oh I missed Spidermonkey... thanks!

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat.apply([1], [[2]])` ==> `[1, 2]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[].concat` is `Array.prototype.concat`.

`Array.concat` is a Firefox-only static method that concatenates one or more arrays and ignores its `this` argument.

Comment: This has to be the answer but curiously MDN doesn't document that method :-)

Comment: Which style is preferred, `[].concat` or `Array.prototype.concat`?

Comment: @eljenso: `[]` is shorter, but it creates an extra array instance.  `Array.prototype` is longer but faster.  Your pick.