# what's the difference between below js codes?

Tags: javascript, prototype

ATT, is there any difference between below implements?
1.

```
var a = [];
f = function(){
    a = [].concat(a,[].slice.call(arguments));
}
```

2.

```
var a = [];
f = function(){
    a = Array.prototype.concat(a,[].slice.call(arguments));
}
```

Comment: What difference would you expect?

Comment: `[].concat === Array.prototype.concat`

Comment: there is no difference.

Comment: this will help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: possible duplicate of [apply function in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669527/apply-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference other than implicitly or explicitly calling `Array.prototype.concat`.

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but the function `f` can be simplified as follows.

```
var a = [];

var f = function() {
    a = a.concat( [].slice.call(arguments) );
}
```

You can find more information about `Array.prototype.concat` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Additionally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) question has a good discussion of prototype functions.

Comment: thanks @Austin, i found the second way in a Chinese famous website named [Douban](http://douban.com), and i was wondering why they are using that way instead of an easier way.